# How to change RAML version in Anypoint Studio project

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, raml, raml-1.0

This might be a bit of a stupid question because I don't know if it is possible but is there a way to change the version of RAML Anypoint Studio project uses (Mule 3.9.1, Studio 6.4)? Currently, when I create a new RAML file, it creates a 0.8 version. I want to use 1.0. I have projects with 1.0 version but I can not remember what was done to have 1.0 instead of 0.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to manually change the header of the file to `#%RAML 1.0`